# ANSI Colours not showing in iTerm2

Tags: iterm

I've tried following answers in this link but I still can't get the ANSI colours in custom themes to show for me in iTerm. Did anyone find any other fixes?

https://superuser.com/questions/399594/color-scheme-not-applied-in-iterm2

Comment: Did you try creating your own theme? Does it work there?

Comment: Yep, I just tried that and no luck.